# yielding a mapped array of promise doesn't return anything

Tags: javascript, generator, promise, bluebird

I am using the promise library `bluebird` with node `0.11.9` running with the flag `--harmony`

I have a simple working example:

```
var Promise = require('bluebird');
var fs = require('fs');
var readdirAsync = Promise.promisify(fs.readdir, fs);
var statAsync = Promise.promisify(fs.stat, fs);

Promise.spawn(function *() {
  var files = yield readdirAsync('./');
  var stats = yield files.map(function(file) { return statAsync(file); });
  console.log(stats);
  console.log('done');
});
```

This works fine and output the list of nodes' stats.
But with the following version: there is no output at all:

```
var Promise = require('bluebird');
var fs = require('fs');
var readdirAsync = Promise.promisify(fs.readdir, fs);
var statAsync = Promise.promisify(fs.stat, fs);

Promise.spawn(function *() {
  var files = yield readdirAsync('./');
  var stats = yield files.map(statAsync);
  console.log(stats);
  console.log('done');
});
```

Any idea of why this doesn't work ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is unfortunately that `Promise.promisify` isn't perfect.  It doesn't know how many arguments `fs.stat` should have.  It passes through whatever arguments you give it, as well as the node style callback.

`Array.prototype.map` doesn't call the mapping function with a single argument.  Instead it gives it the item, the index in the array, and a copy of the array.  Therefore your second example looks like:

```
var Promise = require('bluebird');
var fs = require('fs');
var readdirAsync = Promise.promisify(fs.readdir, fs);
var statAsync = Promise.promisify(fs.stat, fs);

Promise.spawn(function *() {
  var files = yield readdirAsync('./');
  var stats = yield files.map(function(file, i, a) { return statAsync(file, i, a); });
  console.log(stats);
  console.log('done');
});
```

If the callback doesn't appear until the fourth argument, `fs.stat` will never call it.

Comment: Probably worth noting: this isn't blubird's fault but rather a problem with callbacks that isn't easily resolved.

Comment: Thanks, I should've read the source code before asking, this limitation is fairly obvious now you said it.

Comment: Took me a while to work this out when I first saw it